# pageblocktable is not getting displayed in visualforcepage

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, pageblocktable

I am new to salesforce, I am trying to show table with records from account in visualforce page using pagination offset in soql. Pageblocktable is not displaying in visualforce page, please help.

```
public with sharing class soql_offset_example {
    private integer counter=0; //keeps track of the offset
    private integer list_size=20; //set the page size of number of rows
    public integer total_size; //used to show the total list of the size
    public List<Account> accountsRec{get;set;}

    public soql_offset_example(){
        total_size=[select count() from Account]; //sets the total size in the constructor
    }

    public Account[] getNumbers(){
        try{
            Account[] accountsRec=[select name,phone,customer_id__c from Account order by name limit:list_size offset :counter];
            
            return accountsRec;
        } catch(QueryException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public PageReference Beginning(){ //User clicked beginning
        counter=0;
        return null;
    }
    
    public PageReference Previous(){ //User clicked previous button
        counter -=list_size;
        return null;
    }
    
    public PageReference Next(){ //User clicked Next button
        counter +=list_size;
        return null;
    }
    
    public PageReference End(){ //User clicked end
        counter=total_size-math.mod(total_size, list_size);
        return null;
    }
    
    public Boolean getDisablePrevious(){
        //this will disable the previous and beginning buttons
        if(counter>0) return false; else return true;
    }
    
    public Boolean getDisableNext(){
        //this will disable the next and end buttons
        if(counter+list_size<total_size) return false; else return true;
    }
    
    public Integer getTotal_size(){
        return total_size;
    }
    
    public Integer getPageNumber(){
        return counter/list_size+1;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPages(){
        if(math.mod(total_size, list_size)>0){
            return total_size/list_size+1;
        } else{
            return (total_size/list_size);
        }
    }    
}
```

---

```
   <apex:page title="Salesforce SOQL offset example using visualforce"
       controller="soql_offset_example" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" readOnly="true" cache="false">

<apex:sectionHeader subtitle="SOQL Offset Example" title="Account Records"/>

<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:outputPanel id="myButtons">
            <apex:form >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Beginning}" title="Beginning" value="<<"
                                    disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="mypanel,myButtons"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Previous}" title="Previous" value="<"
                                    disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" title="Next" value=">"
                                    disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!End}" title="End" value=">>"
                                    disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <p>
            This example allows a user to paginate up and down through a result set 20 records at a time.
        </p>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Records (Total Size:{!total_size})" collapsible="true">
        <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">
            <apex:pageMessages id="theMessages"/>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountsRec}" var="n">
                <apex:column value="{!n.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!n.Phone}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!n.Customer_ID__c}"/>
                <apex:facet name="footer"> Showing Page # {!PageNumber} of {!totalPages}
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Account[] accountsRec=[select name,phone,customer_id__c from Account order by name limit:list_size offset :counter];
```

This creates a locally scoped variable (see [Name Shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm) for more information). This means the variable bound to your apex:pageBlockSection is never set with a value. Instead, you want to write:

```
accountsRec=[select name,phone,customer_id__c from Account order by name limit:list_size offset :counter];
```

---

In addition, do not write the query with side effects in a [getter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm) method, because you cannot predict the order in which they occur. You should prefer to use queries in action methods or a constructor. Further, you never call getNumbers(), so there's no way the query ever actually runs. Make sure you call it when the page initializes:

```
public soql_offset_example(){
    total_size=[select count() from Account]; //sets the total size in the constructor
    getNumbers();
}
```

As well as in each action method:

```
public void Beginning(){ //User clicked beginning
    counter=0;
    getNumbers();
}
```

Note that action methods do not need to return a PageReference unless you need to redirect the user (hint: you don't do any redirecting here).

---

I also suggest you rename getNumbers to something like getAccounts, which is what you're actually doing.

---

We're allowed to have **40** characters per variable name. I advise against using `accountRecs`. Simply call it either `accounts` or `accountRecords`. It doesn't make sense to use weird abbreviations when you can simply call the variable what it is. You want your code to be readable, and this includes writing proper variable and method names.

---

Finally, it's worth noting that there's already a system library that does what you're trying to do: [ApexPages.StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm). You simply give it an inline query, and it provides you with all the pagination functions you need to implement your goals, including navigating the list and setting the per-page list size.

Comment: @peter Thanks a lot for the quick help, I am now getting table on the page. Thanks for also guiding with a tips on how we can write code better, will note these points.